# Chamando um script do tipo text/x-kendo-template a partir de uma função javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Eu tenho [este](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDjd3.png) novo botão e no evento `onclick` estou chamando a função `openEditor()`, e dentro desta função eu quero chamar um script do tipo `text/x-kendo-template`. Como posso fazer isso?

Meu código atualmente:

**Botão customizado**:

```
schedulerToolbar.append(
"<ul class='k-reset'>
   <li class='k-state-default'>
     <a role='button' href='#' class='k-link newMeetingButton' onclick='openEditor()'>
       Nova reserva
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>"
)
```

**Função openEditor()**:

```
function openEditor() {
   *código para chamar o script customEditorTemplateBh*
}
```

**Script do Template**:

```
<script id="customEditorTemplateBh" type="text/x-kendo-template"> 
   *código do template*
</script>
```

Estou usando o componente kendo scheduler e adicionei aquele botão customizado na toolbar do componente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seguinte código em openEditor() foi o suficiente:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler-bh").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.addEvent({ });
```